# Can the Onsen UI Javascript and CSS frameworks be used with Worklight Hybrid Applications?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, onsen-ui

Can I use Onsen UI with my Worklight hybrid applications?  Specifically, while using the Worklight Studio for development?

Since it seems to be compatible with Cordova and JQuery on the surface it looks like it does.

Comment: One thing is for sure - you can't use their tools. You will need to add the files manually. AngularJS works fine with Worklight, with with manual work and tinkering you might get it to work - anyway, this is IMO totally off topic to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Idan said, you'll need to perform some manual work and you cannot use cordova tools. I was able to create a WL hybrid app project, add the references as in their Guide, deploy to WL Server and open the app in the Mobile Browser Simulator. It took 3 minutes.